# Saxon Config file using PE: Extension elements are not available in Saxon-HE

Tags: xml, config, saxon

I am trying to use saxon-sql-10.2.jar with saxon-pe-10.2.jar. Having read through the Saxon  documentation ([instructions](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sql-extension/instructions/), [example](https://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/sql-extension/instructions/example.html)), I found I should be using a config file which I created using an Oxygen template:

```
<configuration edition="PE" xmlns="http://saxon.sf.net/ns/configuration" label="Some label">

    <xslt recoveryPolicy="recoverWithWarnings" schemaAware="false" staticErrorListener=""
        staticUriResolver="" styleParser="" version="3.0" versionWarning="false">
      
        <extensionElement namespace="http://saxon.sf.net/sql"
            factory="net.sf.saxon.option.sql.SQLElementFactory"/>
    </xslt>
</configuration>
```

In cmd I have:

```
java -cp "%SAXON_HOME%\saxon-pe-10.2.jar;%SAXON_HOME%\saxon-sql-10.2.jar;" net.sf.saxon.Transform -s:test.xml -xsl:DB.xsl -o:out.xml -config:config.xml -t
```

But when this runs I get the message:

```
Warning on line 19 column 69 of config.xml:
   Extension elements are not available in Saxon-HE
```

Why am I getting this message when I am using PE? I have verified my license file is being read correctly using a Saxon query and have tried the config file both with and without specifying the license file location. All of my Saxon related files are in c:\saxon, which has the environment variable `%SAXON_HOME%`. I have also tried using `-classpath` instead of `-cp` and adding the license file to both but this has not helped. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced this, it's a bug. Raised at

https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4849

I can't think of a convenient workaround, so get in touch with us and we'll give you a temporary upgrade to Saxon-EE so you can make progress.